# Encrypt text with PKCS1_OAEP python

Tags: python-2.7, cryptography

I try to encrypt/decrypt with private and public key. If i both encrypt and decrypt in one program all work. But if i save the encrypted message and then try to decrypt from the file i get

> ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.

Here is an working code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP as cip
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
message = open('message.txt','r').read(500)
key =RSA.importKey(open('public.pem').read())
cipher = cip.new(key)
crypt = cipher.encrypt(message)




key = RSA.importKey(open('privkey.pem').read())
sentinel ={"error":True}
cipher = cip.new(key)
message = cipher.decrypt(crypt)
with open('Decrypted message.txt','w') as fil:
  fil.write(message)
```

And not working:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP as cip
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
message = open('message.txt','r').read(500)
key =RSA.importKey(open('public.pem').read())
cipher = cip.new(key)
crypt = cipher.encrypt(message)
with open('crypted.txt','w') as file_write:
  file_write.write(crypt)




key = RSA.importKey(open('privkey.pem').read())
sentinel ={"error":True}
cipher = cip.new(key)
message = cipher.decrypt(open('crypted.txt','r').read())
with open('Decrypted message.txt','w') as fil:
  fil.write(message)
```

Comment: What was the length of the data you encrypted?

Comment: In the test code I just encrypt abc.. So it's not the length of data that cause the problem.. I think it's something with write/read.....

Comment: Save/load it as binary using the `b` flag.